# Aliased LEFT JOIN affects SUM unexpectedly

Tags: mysql

Why do the two queries below give different results? I thought that joins in the case like those below shouldn't interact with each other, but they apparently are.

The query:

```
SELECT
  s.id,
  SUM(CASE WHEN n.template_id = 1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS template_1
FROM schedulings AS s
LEFT JOIN notes AS calls_made
  ON s.id = calls_made.schedule_id
  AND calls_made.template_id IN (1, 2, 3, 5, 6, 9, 10, 11, 12, 14)
LEFT OUTER JOIN notes AS n
  ON s.id = n.schedule_id
WHERE s.id = 48810;
```

The results:

```
id      template_1
48810   70
```

However, if I change the query by commenting out (or removing) the first notes join, I get the expected result.

The query:

```
SELECT
  s.id,
  SUM(CASE WHEN n.template_id = 1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS template_1
FROM schedulings AS s
LEFT OUTER JOIN notes AS n
  ON s.id = n.schedule_id
WHERE s.id = 48810;
```

The result:

```
id      template_1
48810   7
```

Comment: _"I thought that joins in the case like those below shouldn't interact with each other"_ this was where you were misinformed. Aggregation happens after all joining, subqueries, etc... in the FROM.

Comment: Even though my aggregation is using an aliased table, SQL is going to look at all of the tables to perform the aggregation? That seems not only silly, but wrong.

Comment: SQL looks at the results of the FROM (and WHERE obviously) to do the aggregation, aliases don't really factor into the matter aside from distinguishing which fields of the pre-aggregate results to be used.

Comment: @Uueerdo is correct with his first comment. Not sure what the issue is here... also `template_id` is filtered in one join and not the other, so obviously that's where the discretion originates from. Or do I not understand what you're trying to discern?

Comment: @Eugene I need both joins for different pieces of information, but I need the second join specifically to provide a count of each individual note. There are actually even more joins being done with the `notes` table, which is what triggered the investigation in the first place.

Comment: @GlenSolsberry You may want to look into conditional aggregation rather than multiple joins instead. Your queries' result fields don't make it obvious what the additional joins are for, but I would suspect perhaps something like this in the SELECT could be helpful `COUNT(CASE WHEN n.template_id IN (1, 2, 3....) THEN 1 ELSE NULL END) AS calls_made_count` _(Note: my use of ... is just short hand)_

Comment: OK, so is your question regarding how `LEFT JOIN` and `LEFT OUTER JOIN` work in MySQL (the result does not appear unexpected to me, given the information). I will gladly rewrite complete SQL with explanation if you are stuck, but the question as it stands seems either incomplete or redundant...

Comment: I mean, no offence or anything, I just want to help!